# .NET Sync services - says upload failed, but upload is successful done on server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

am using Sync services v1.
The strange thing is that if i make changed to local DB and syncing them Sync event shows that x changes uploaded, x upload failed (the x amount is the same).

BUT the changes is done on remote server, so why does Sync says it failed?

Answer (score 1):

subscribe to ApplyChangeFailed event, look at the type of conflict/error then examine the source and destination row in the event handler to figure out why it's failing.

Comment: Thanks for replay, but i can't find such event on my DBSyncAgent or in ServerSyncProviderProxy. Only two events - SessionProgress and StateChanged.

Comment: a quick search on ApplyChangeFailed would have netted you lots of reaources. i updated the answer to point to a tutorial on how to handle conflicts. btw, you're proxy will not have the event handler. ServerSyncProviderProxy is a proxy for code that executes on the remotes side. dont expect it to fire and raise events back to the client.